# Failed to install ipa file programatically in iOS 6

Tags: ios6, installation, jailbreak, ipa

I use MobileInstallationInstall to install ipa files in a jailbreak iOS.
It works well in iOS5, but it fails in iOS6.
I checked the logs and find the following:

**required to have an entitlement named "com.apple.private.mobileinstall.allowedSPI" with an array containing "Install" to call command Install**

Then I added a entitlement in .entitlements file which named "com.apple.private.mobileinstall.allowedSPI" with an array containing "Install"

But it still fails.
How can I fix it?

Comment: OK follow the [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871748/how-do-i-change-my-applications-entitlements-to-com-apple-backboard-client] And need to add the follwoing to xml file 
<key>com.apple.private.mobileinstall.allowedSPI</key>
 <array>
  <string>Install</string>
  <string>Browse</string>
  <string>Uninstall</string>
  <string>Archive</string>
  <string>RemoveArchive</string>
 </array>