# ios entitlements in jailbreak solution iOSOpenDev

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi

I am using MobileWifi private framework to list all access points. Its a jailbroken phone and I use iOSOpenDev to compile and deploy. I included entitlements.xml in Project->BuildSettings->"Code Signing Entitlements"

XML has

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.wifi.manager-access</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I still get error

```
_wifi_manager_open Client WifiTest has no entitlement
```

I think I am missing the right way to add entitlements. Any ideas how to make it work?

**EDIT:**
So I used ldid to sign the app per your previous answer. ldid gave following output.

```
WifiTest
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>application-identifier</key>
<string>ECZNUJJL7C.com.WifiTest</string>
<key>get-task-allow</key>
<true/>
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
    <string>ECZNUJJL7C.com.WifiTest</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I am assuming it signed the app. Then using iExplorer I transferred the WifiTest.app directly on device. It crashes. Logs show..

```
Sep  6 16:02:31  com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.WifiTest[0x4d49][19575]) <Error>: (UIKitApplication:com.WifiTest[0x4d49]) posix_spawn("/var/mobile/Applications/CCCAA7CB-2304-4A99-8306-20234E38652F/WifiTest.app/WifiTest", ...): Permission denied


Sep  6 16:02:31  SpringBoard[19291] <Warning>: Unable to obtain a task name port right for pid 19575: (os/kern) failure


Sep  6 16:02:31  com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.WifiTest[0x4d49][19575]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.WifiTest[0x4d49]) Exited with code: 1


Sep  6 16:02:31  SpringBoard[19291] <Warning>: Unable to look up event port name for pid 19575: (os/kern) successful


Sep  6 16:02:31  SpringBoard[19291] <Warning>: Unable to send activation event to <SBApplication: 0xd223be0> com.WifiTest animate statusBarOrientation = 1  activate: animationStart = 0  deactivate: : (ipc/send) invalid destination port
```

Comment: @Nate - So I was hooking the tweak(which is separate dylib) with my custom app and it did not have the entitlements. If I hook it with SpringBoard it works.. If I apply entitlements to my custom app, xcode throws error as custom app is not a tweak or legos project.. any ideas how to make it work...

Comment: @Nate - I have also added complete xml in question.

Comment: @Nate - I also tried using "codesign -f -s <identity> --entitlements entitlements.xml <executable>" - I used identity as the developer license that I already have.. But I am signing dylib. Not the custom app that actually hooks and invokes tweak.. Should I be?

Comment: So, I'm not using iOSOpenDev right now ... just normal Xcode.  But, in general, I don't add entitlements via my Xcode project.  I build inside Xcode without code signing at all, and then run a one line command with `ldid` afterwords to fake codesign and add entitlements.xml file, all at once.  [Have you tried this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14885266/119114)?  If you already have iOSOpenDev installed, it will have done a couple of those steps for you.

Comment: So, the important thing would be to add the entitlements to your app, not the dylib that it uses.  Even if the dylib is the one making the MobileWifi calls, I think you need to sign the app executable that will be running it.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Great, Let me try it and get back in few hours.. Thx for your help...

Comment: I don't understand your `ldid` output.  `ldid` normally doesn't have any output.  Are you saying that you ran `ldid -Sentitlements.xml WifiTest`, and then, **after that**, you ran `ldid -e WifiTest` just to *list* the entitlements ... double-checking what you've done?

Comment: @Nate - I just executed one command - ldid -entitlements.xml WifiTest. It still echoed the XML which is slightly different that original input xml..

Comment: there is a capital S before the name of the xml file.  do you have that?

Comment: @Nate - Thanks. yes I had missed S as I thought its not my file name and failed to realize its a flag(I was literally dumb).. Now I was able to sign without any output and also verify the signature with -e command. I tried installing the .app via iExplorer. It gets copied but does not show icon on SpringBoard even after killall -HUP SpringBoard.. So how do I convert .app to .ipa and install?

Comment: Ok, so I'm going to recommend that you ask a new question.  If you've successfully signed the app (or fake signed with `ldid`), and added the entitlements, then the problem converting an app to an installable .ipa file is really a separate problem.  I'd also recommend you just delete this question, because if the problem was just a missing `S` in the command line, I don't think many others will be helped by seeing this question and answer.   It's your decision, but that's my recommendation.  If you create a new question, just asking about the .ipa installation, I can try to take a look.  Thx.

Comment: Thanks Nate - I posted a new question. I will also delete this answer later.