# Adding Custom Entitlements To In-House App

Tags: ios, codesign, code-signing-entitlements

I am attempting to add a CUSTOM entitlement (com.apple.private.bmk.allow) to an Enterprise App.

I first built the app with XCode, then extracted the existing entitlement plist file, and added the custom entitlement entry.  Next, I used codesign to resign the app and include the entitlement plist with the addition I had made.

However, when I attempt to install the app via an enterprise link, the app begins installing, then fails with error:

> verify_signer_identity: MISValidateSignatureAndCopyInfo failed for
>   /var/tmp/install_staging.sveECd/foo_extracted/Payload/test.app/test:
>   0xe8008016
>
> installd[45] : 0x295000 do_preflight_verification: Could not
>   verify executable at
>   /var/tmp/install_staging.sveECd/foo_extracted/Payload/test.app

If I remove the custom entitlement entry that I added, then the app installs just fine.  It appears that adding ANYTHING to the existing entitlement file prevents it from installing.  Is there any way to add a custom entitlement that will install on a device ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971137/does-ios-enterprise-program-allow-to-add-entitlements-to-provisioning-profiles

Comment: but what about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648995/ios-entitlements-in-jailbreak-solution-iosopendev ? can apps signed with ldid be installed via Enterprise links ?