# objective c - Help about ldid log

Tags: ios, objective-c, build, jailbreak, entitlements

i'm using "ldid" to change entitlements in my app and I do exactly here: [How do I change my iOS applications' entitlements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871748/how-do-i-change-my-ios-applications-entitlements)

But i got this log:

```
_assert(0:Swap(mach_header_->magic) == MH_MAGIC)
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

and my app still not changed entitlements

Any one help me, i'm newbie, thanks

Comment: Did you build your app for iOS (not for the simulator)?  And did you build it for one architecture, or multiple architectures?  And, where did you get the `ldid` binary from?  Please update your question with these answers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yep i buit it in my device (not simulator), one architecture --- 
I got that error when i run this in Terminal: Example: $ldid -Setm.xml helloworld.app/helloworld ---- I download ldid form here: https://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/detail?name=ldid